# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query though able to get result from sql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to excute a hibernate query

```
    final StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(50);
    sql.append("SELECT DISTINCT  SN.GTIN || ',' || SN.BATCH_NBR||','||SN.EXPIRATION_DATE||','||SN.SRL_NBR  from C_SRL_NBR SN");
    sql.append(" WHERE TC_LPN_ID =:cartonNum");

    final String[] nameList = { "cartonNum" };
    final Object[] parmList = { cartonNum };

    List<String> columnName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Type> columnType = new ArrayList<>();

    columnName.add("GTIN");
    columnName.add("BATCH_NBR");
    columnName.add("EXPIRATION_DATE");
    columnName.add("SRL_NBR");
    columnType.add(Type.STRING);
    columnType.add(Type.STRING);
    columnType.add(Type.STRING);
    columnType.add(Type.STRING);

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<String> list = directSQLQuery(sql.toString(), nameList, parmList, columnName, columnType);
        if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
            return list;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
        throw new DataAccessException(e);
    }
```

when I am running the query in db it is giving me output but through code it is giving exception can any one please help with this

Comment: can you share directSQLQuery implementation? Also share the exception which was thrown with stack trace.

Comment: hello wasim  thanks for replynig ,I was able to resolve this,the thing  i was doing wrong is after updating the records in db i didn't commited i.e the reason it was not coming.